# Java If loop too many clicks to reset

Tags: java, android, loops, if-statement

I have a button that when clicked should count up until it reaches the resetTouch limit and then reset to 0.

However that is not what is happening.

```
    int resetTouch = 4;
    int number = 1;
    int touches1 = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    //adds number of touches
    public void setTouches1 (View view){

        if (touches1 < resetTouch){
           touches1 = touches1 + number;

           displayTeamTouches(touches1);
}
           else{
            touches1 = 0;
        }
```

This sorta works, however instead of stopping at 3 it goes to 4. I have to click the + button twice at this point to get it to reset to 1. I want it to increment to 3 and then reset to 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: touches1++;  or touches1 += number;

Answer (score 1):

By the time you observe `touches1`, it has already incremented.  Your first runs would look like 1, 2, 3, 4, and *then* it would reset.

You should observe the variable *before* you increment it.  This way, you can actually see 0, 1, 2, 3 instead.

```
if(touches1 < resetTouch) {
    displayTeamTouches(touches1);
    touches1 += number;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is resetting correctly  but it is staying at 3 for two clicks before it resets.